# In-app purchase Non-Consumable working with me perfectly but not with apple viewer

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have In-app purchase Non-Consumable on my app and I'm using keychain to save the state of in-app purchase there. However, it was working perfectly with me by using sandbox. I've tried it on 2 devices and on the simulator. But, when I the reviewer tried my app, he has unlimited access to all the features which are not supposed to be access before the user make an in-app purchase. My question is, is it possible that another app the reviewer has sharing the same key and that key works on both apps? Or what could be the problem?

```
  func buy(){
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        let transactionRequest = SKMutablePayment()
        transactionRequest.productIdentifier = PurchaseID
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(transactionRequest)
    }else {
        print("User cannot make the trancation")
    }
}

  func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        if transaction.transactionState == .purchased {
            purchased = true
            keychain.set(purchased, forKey: "purchased")
            
            resetView()
            print("transaction is successful")
        }else if transaction.transactionState == .failed {
            purchased = false
            keychain.set(purchased, forKey: "purchased")
            print("The transaction has failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Retrieve in-app purchase value

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
        if let pur = keychain.getBool("purchased"){
             purchased = pur
        }
  }
```

Then I use purchased value to check if it should allows users to add a new list or not

```
@IBAction func addList(_ sender: Any) {
    if lists.count > 0 && purchased == false{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: transTitle, message: transMsg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: transOK, style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        let buyAction = UIAlertAction(title: transBuy, style: .default, handler: self.buyAlert)
        alert.addAction(OKAction)
        alert.addAction(buyAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else {
        let addCatVC = children.last as! AddCategoryViewController
        addCatVC.checkPur()
        AddListContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        AddListContainer.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.addSubview(blockScreen)
        blockScreen.addSubview(AddListContainer)
        AddListContainer.isHidden = false
        blockScreen.isHidden = false
        blockScreen.alpha = 1
        
        
    }  
}
```

However, I’m allowing the user to add only one list before buying all features. Also, I’m using purchased value with other classes, for example if a user create a list, he/she can only add up to 10 items on that list before buying for in app purchases. It is working on my devices and simulator perfectly but when Apple review my application they said, they can access to all features without buying.

Comment: You aren't calling `finishTransaction`, but more importantly, show the code where you fetch the value from the keychain and unlock the features.  It also doesn't make sense to set the keychain to `false` in the `.failed` state. Just don't do anything except finish the transaction and let the user know there was a problem.

Comment: Also, the keychain is part of your app sandbox, so no other app can put items in your apps keychain

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll add finishTransaction and notify the users about the error. However, when users make a purchase, it call a resetView() method which is basically has if purchased == true { unlock all features } and that if statement is located also in ViewDidLoad().

Comment: Also, I submitted my application 3 time and get rejected for different reasons. So, is it possible that the reviewer already tried in app purchases on the previous build so he/she got all the features already available?

Comment: It's not likely. You would probably have different reviewers each time. Please show the code where you fetch and check for the purchase when your app starts.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I edited my post added more details.

Comment: The key in your `set` is different to the key in your `get`. Have you tried a TestFlight build? How do you initialise `purchased`?  A better line of code might be `purchased = keychain.getBool("com.lahint.purchased") ?? false`

Comment: Sorry I edited the key before I send it again to Apple and I forgot to edited also in my post. So, it is the same in my actual code. I initialise purchased like this var purchased = false. I didn’t try TestFlight build.